# How do I setup a camera in a fixed position?

Tags: webvideos

Im interested in creating a video stream channel. There are cases where say I'm building a computer that I want to place a WebCam in a fixed position above my head. Or say doing a car repair, I will need a similar set up.   Most web cameras I've seen are designed to be attached to a computer directly.  Im imagining a stand and a camera attached to it.  Ideally, the camera attaches to a PC but it doesn't have to.

I guess I could pull this off with my iPhone if it had a stand to hold it.

Comment: I've shot many videos on my phone and they come out great. You can also get an inexpensive tripod; I saw one about the size of my hand that can grip onto things like the neck of a floor lamp, and it only cost $5.

Comment: @BrettFromLA I already have a Tripod.  I found an iPhone 6S mount for tripods that I'm definitely gonna try!  https://www.amazon.com/dp/B016KZDN5M/ref=twister_B016KZDLPE?_encoding=UTF8&psc=1

Comment: Make sure to shoot with the primary camera on your iPhone 6S, not your secondary phone. I just Googled them and they have significantly different quality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get a camera (not a webcam), any camera, and put it on a tripod. Make sure the camera has the approriate mount to put it on your tripod. If you have a camera without such mount, just prop it up against some books or something like this. Then connect your camera to your PC (for live streaming) or just record to SD card and put it on your computer later (for prerecorded video).

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing wrong with using a WebCam instead of a camera, provided you have a long enough cable.  There are USB extension chords that can give you a few extra feet, and USB extenders that can go quite far (over Cat6a cable, for example).

But regardless of whether you use a webcam (that interfaces as a digital device to your computer) or a camera (which interfaces as a digital video stream to a video capture card in your computer), you do need something to fix it to.  In the world of video, the department that supplies such this is the GRIP department.  If you visit sites on the web that cater to the video world, look for GRIP and that will bring you to the wide variety of clamps, mounts, screws, plates, etc., that attach to your camera on one side and to something in your room or the ground on the other.